# Registry checking if path/key exists

Tags: java, registry

Hei guys, quick stupid question...

I got this code:

```
String arch = System.getenv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE");
String wow64Arch = System.getenv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432");
String realArch = arch.endsWith("64") || wow64Arch != null && wow64Arch.endsWith("64") ? "64" : "32";
String setWin = ((realArch.contains("64")) ? "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\path" : "SOFTWARE\\path");
String check = Advapi32Util.registryGetStringValue (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, setWin, "InstallDir");
```

Which strings a path to a installed application, but if the registry doesn't exists my program stops.
How i can check if the registry exists and if doesn't bypass it?

and also to add `system.err.println("Application not installed.");` if the key doesn't exists.

PS: The program is a GUI so i want to show it even if the key is missing.

Thank you!

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Sam. I did found something, not sure if it will fail at one point ...

```
public void checkInstalled(){
    try {
        String regValue = null;
            regValue = WinRegistry.valueForKey(WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, setWin, "InstallDir");
        if(regValue == null){
            System.err.println("Application not installed!");
        } else {
            "do the other thing"
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
```